# Inner Join where all conditions on dynamic table are met

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

First time asking a question on here so going to try and summarize as well as I can.

I'm working on a keyword system for a search function. I have the criteria made at runtime by parameters and selected on the front end. I have managed to make a system where a special character is used to define how the search works for 'or' I use ('|') and for 'and' I use ('&') but can't get the logic right for the and function.

How the 'or' method works is by using UDF to split the string into a table (e.g. the string passed is 'Testing|Check' and this will be returned as '%Testing%' and '%Check%'). I call this function as shown below and append it onto the end of my query with existing conditions.

```
select Title from vwIncidentSearchView 
inner join dbo.MultipleTextSearchValuesOR('Testing|Check') on Title Like id
```

This works as intended and I have setup the UDF split for the 'and'. What I'm struggling to do is getting the 'and' functionality to work. I would like it to work in a similar way to how I call the 'or' function but it must require all checks to be valid.

I was thinking is there maybe a method of seeing how many times each entry meets the criteria and if it's is equal to the table entries to include it? I will be needing the 'like' functionality as well

Hopefully that makes enough sense for some help. Any points unclear I'll do my best to explain them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made new post, this can be deleted or left it, link to new with an answer - [Select entries that fulfil requirements laid out by dynamic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110404/select-entries-that-fulfil-requirements-laid-out-by-dynamic-table/65393946#65393946)