# Select entries that fulfil requirements laid out by dynamic table

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements, keyword

I'm attempting to do a keyword search which requires all conditions to be met for a result to be shown. I've created a method of making a custom table from a string which stores all of the keywords which are currently required for this search.

I've been able to get it to happen for 'or' using the following

dbo.MultipleTextSearchValuesOR - Is used to make the table of keywords

```
select Title from vwIncidentSearchView inner join dbo.MultipleTextSearchValuesOR('Testing|Check') on Title Like id
```

This works great but can't seem to work it out for 'and' (e.g. result must have 'Testing' and 'Check').

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. The way it had to be done was using a cross apply with a function splitting the string into a table.

Then the entries must be grouped by all the fields. Finally they must be checked to see if it meets all the required keywords.

I do realise this is quite a messy method along with it not beingthe most optimized method so if anyone else has any suggestions to improving performance it would be appreciated

Example:

```
declare @where nvarchar(max)
declare @TitleLikeClause nvarchar(max)
declare @Title nvarchar(max)

set @Title = 'Down&Email'

SELECT 
       Referenceid, 
       Title 
FROM vwIncidentSearchView  
cross apply
       (select 
             Data 
       from Split(@Title, '&') candidate 
       where 
             Title Like candidate.Data) t2o group by Referenceid, Title having count(*) = (select max(ID) from Split(@Title, '&'))
```